# Join Table by previous top (max) date

Tags: sql

I have the following problem: I have two tables, one is accounts table with transactions in it (there can be multiple transactions in a sigle day), another is a table with account balances (where the balance at the end of the day is recorded; since tranactions don't occur everyday the balance table has date 'gaps' like: 2014-01-05 800 USD the next row is 2014-02-03 600 USD). I need to join the tables to get the initial balance of the day (max previous date in balance table).

```
select CLIENT_ID, TRANSACTION_ID, AMOUNT, DATE from TRANSACTIONS
```

balance table:

```
select CLIENT_ID, DATE, BALANCE from BALANCE
```

I need something like

```
select * 
from TRANSACTIONS t 
   inner join BALANCE b on b.CLIENT_ID = t.CLIENT_ID and t.DATE > b.DATE
```

(here should be previous max date)

```
select * 
from TRANSACTIONS t 
   inner join BALANCE b 
           on b.CLIENT_ID = t.CLIENT_ID 
          and t.DATE = (select max (bl.DATE) 
                        from BALANCE bl 
                        where t.CLIENT = bl.CLIENT_ID 
                        and bl.DATE < t.DATE)
```

Comment: why are you joining, you can get the balance from `balance` table itself ?

Comment: then I'll get the end of day balance, I need the start of day balance

Comment: but you are saying the `balance` table contains the balance at the end of the day so I can use it as next day's balance, right ?

Comment: select * from TRANSACTIONS t inner join BALANCE b on b.CLIENT_ID = t.CLIENT_ID and t.DATE = (select max (bl.DATE) from BALANCE bl where t.CLIENT = bl.CLIENT_ID and bl.DATE < t.DATE)

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?